# NPE during entitiManagerFactory creation

Tags: java, jpa

Trying to add JPA/Hibernate  to my project w/o Spring always see NPE.
My pom:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <hibernate-version>6.0.0.Alpha5</hibernate-version>
</properties>
```

org.junit.jupiter
           junit-jupiter-api
           5.6.2
           test
       
       
           org.projectlombok
           lombok
           1.18.12
           provided

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.28</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.13.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.200</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

Here is persistence.xml:
[image: persistence]

My repository class:

```
    public class PlaceJpaRepository implements IPlaceRepository {
      EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( 
      "com.senla.carservice.jpa.hibernate" );
      EntityManager manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    **Bunch of CRUD methods**
 }
```

*Entity class:*

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Place {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @Embedded
    private Calendar calendar;


    public Place(Calendar calendar) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.calendar = calendar;

    }

}
```

After creating PlaceJpaRepository it falls with NPE at

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( 
          "com.senla.carservice.jpa.hibernate" );
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$1(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1682)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1681)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1659)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1681)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1667)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1217)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1248)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.senla.carservice.domain.repository.jpa.PlaceJpaRepository.<init>(PlaceJpaRepository.java:18)
    at TestJpaRepo.testAdd(TestJpaRepo.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

After I logged into console embedded base, logger shows message:

> Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode

After I loggout app throws NPE as usual.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was the version of hibernate. After switching to 5.4.12 it works properly.

Comment: Tip: if a version contains things like `Alpha` or `Beta`, it means they are pre-release versions and can contain (severe) bugs.

Comment: Do you encounter the same issue if you use the latest Alpha 6 release ? https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-orm/6.0.0.Alpha6/